# Refresh Internet Explorer_Server from handler

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, ihtmldocument2

Is it possible to force Internet `Explorer_Server` to refresh it content?
What I have is a handler to that object in external application (like in my [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439081/ihtmldocument2-click-button-inside-iframe) question)

I found a nice tutorial on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8256/Invoke-Hidden-Commands-in-Your-WebBrowser) that shows how to do that in MFC, but I would like to do that from C#.

My question is: How to refresh Internet `Explorer_Server` that is hosted in external application.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but I assume you are already referencing `mshtml` assembly in your C# project?

I am betting if you experiment with the `IHTMLDocument2.open` method you might find a way to do this. I am running out to the airport, so I can't experiment with his or test it right now. But this link has some useful info (note: while the link refers to win API code, that code is modeled in the .net implementation through `IHTMLDocuement2` interface in the `mshtml` assembly).

[msdn on IHTMLDocument2.open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have had good luck using the mshtml assembly in C# for other operations, although it took a little work and trial and error. Pay particular attention to the parameter for _BSTR as _SELF, and pass the current uri.

Comment: thanks for great tip :) I almost worked. In C# I must pass 4 arguments to that function `(string url, object name, object features, object replace)`. First argument is easy, but I have problem with other 3, because if I pass `""` page is opening in new IE windows instead of opening inside that Internet Explorer_Server control.

Comment: I think that is where you pass the "_SELF" Argument. Interested to know how you finally solve this . . .

Comment: And I mean, literally, pass the string argument "_SELF"

Comment: thanks for tips :) I spend almost 2 days searching for a way to do this. My idea was to invoke click event on specific element as I only needed one table to refresh. I managed to solve my problem and right now I'm improving my code to show that solution. I wasn't able to get inside my iframes because of cross thread access. Give me some time and I'll write my solution :)