# Manipulating HTML elements in 'Internet Explorer_server' using JNA

Tags: java, jna

I'm creating an autologin application using Java and came to a dead end while trying to get the html contents of the Internet Explorer_Server using JNA.

There are some information about this problem in other programming languages, like Python or C#, but couldn't find how to do this in Java. People are using ObjectFromLresult method to get html contents but I can't find any alternative  in Java.
[IHTMLDocument2 - click button inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439081/ihtmldocument2-click-button-inside-iframe)

I successfully connect to window and can send a WM_HTML_GETOBJECT message but I have no idea how to get html contents from LResult.

```java
        WinDef.HWND hWnd = user32.FindWindow("ADALWebBrowserHost","");
        if(hWnd != null){
            ieServer = hWnd;
            while(!ieServerFound) {
                getIEServer gies = new getIEServer();
                user32.EnumChildWindows(ieServer, gies, null);
            }
            int msg = user32.RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
            WinDef.DWORDByReference dbr = new WinDef.DWORDByReference();
            WinDef.LRESULT result = user32.SendMessageTimeout(ieServer, msg, new WinDef.WPARAM(0),new WinDef.LPARAM(0), WinUser.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,1000, dbr);
            // HTML ObjectFromLresult?
        }
```

Is there any way to convert LResult to some kind of array of HTML objects in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the [ObjectFromLresult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-objectfromlresult) function to JNA.  It's not currently in the user-contributed `jna-platform` library.

You'll want to define an `Oleacc` class to fetch from the `oleacc.dll` library this function resides in, and map that function.

```
public interface Oleacc extends StdCallLibrary, WinUser {
    public static final Oleacc INSTANCE = 
            (Oleacc)Native.loadLibrary("oleacc", Oleacc.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);    

    HRESULT ObjectFromLresult(WinDef.LRESULT lResult, Guid.REFIID riid, WinDef.WPARAM wParam, 
            PointerByReference ppvObject);
}
```

Note that the above linked documentation states:

> This function is designed for internal use by Microsoft Active
>   Accessibility and is documented for informational purposes only.
>   Neither clients nor servers should call this function.

So you should not rely on this API for production code.  But assuming you've gotten this far, you'll need to cast that returned Pointer to an [`IHTMLDocument2` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v%3Dvs.85)).  That'll be a class somewhat like this:

```
class IHTMLDocument2 extends IDispatch {
    public IHTMLDocument2() {
    }

    public IHTMLDocument2(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
    }

    // map function(s) here
}
```

In order to map the function you'll define a JNA method [matching the function signature in the header file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574%28v%3Dvs.85%29) which will wrap an `_invokeNativeObject()` call passing the arguments something like this:

```
return (HRESULT) _invokeNativeObject(123,
                new Object[] { foo, bar }, HRESULT.class);
```

You'll replace 123 with the 0-based index of the function/method in the [IHTMLDocument2Vtbl](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/666f7501d03983f84833a7a1952e78fd0650fde6/dlls/mshtml/htmldoc.c#L1819) class in the header file.